# FreeBSD 8.2 STABLE installation failing on VirtualBox

Tags: freebsd, virtualbox, system-installation

On my pc-bsd box, I installed `VirtualBox` and trying to install FreeBSD 8.2 STABLE in 10GB space.

During installation, I selected all the default settings, it looks like this:
[image: Disk layout]

But after this, I get this error:

[image: error]

How can I overcome it?

Comment: Is there a reason `ad0s1c` doesn't exist? Also, you might want to consider making individual virtual hard drives in VirtualBox instead of using partitions.

Comment: @MaxMackie you misunderstand the BSD meaning of a "partition" - using linux nomenclature, it is *all* on a single disk partition. The *disk partitions* on BSD systems are called *slices* - all the above filesystems are on a single *slice*.

Comment: @MaxMackie Yes, there is a reason why `ad0s1c` is not visible - it represents all the remaining part of the disk. Read how the BSD partitions, more often **[called disklabels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_disklabel)** are arranged.

Comment: @hari How did you create the virtual disk - is it **fixed size**, or not? Also, did you properly set the *virtual machine type* to FreeBSD?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz I do not know what you mean by virtual disk. I just created VirtualBox setup with 10GB reserved and also set the virtual machine type to FreeBSD.

Comment: The 10GB that you reserved is the virtual disk size. When you do that, there are two options - an *auto-expanding* disk image (the default) or a fixed-size one. Since you don't remember that, I assume you used the default (auto-expanding).

Comment: I asked about the disk type because I thought it must be fixed for FreeBSD, but I see no evidence of this. Instead, what all such problem cases indicate is that you probably **did not commit disklabel changes to disk before proceeding with the installation**. Repeat that.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz how do I explicitly `commit` disklable changes. In the question, on screen 1 (where I saw the partition info) I did "Q = Finish". Is that not right? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Look, it's been several years now since I've used FreeBSD - **you** should find it yourself - there evidently is a help screen available ("`Use F1 or ? to get more help`"); maybe it's not done at *that particular point* but one step further, which you could have overlooked... I don't know and I won't do all the work for you.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz Thanks for your help so far. I am *not* asking you to do all the work. I am doing the work. Because you replied to my question with your suggestions, I wanted to understand how you came to those conclusions. Never mind, thanks :-)

Comment: Deleted that instance and tried another installation which worked fine. Sometimes its the only thing that can help you. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted that instance and tried another installation which worked fine. Sometimes its the only thing that can help you. Thanks for all the help. I am responding to this question so that it stays in record and someone else hitting this issue can get some help.